# Maven entries with date/timestamps in the filename installed in local repository - in addition to SNAPSHOT

Tags: maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

As shown in the screenshot - in the local `maven` repository there is a mix of `SNAPSHOT` entries (expected!) and date/timestamp entries (not!):

[image]

The issue is that `Intellij` is in some cases picking up the timestamped jars instead of the `SNAPSHOT` ones and that is leading to some mismatches when trying to load the `source` jars - since *those* are *not* generated with timestamps.

So why are these date/timestamp jars created - and why only the binaries and not the source jars?  Can this be configured/controlled?

**Update**   I have manually deleted the files with date/timestamp in their names. *Intellij then **regenerates a new date/timestamp** jar  . Why is it doing this?

Here we can see the difference between  `examples` project and `graphx` : in the former it is correctly using `SNAPSHOT` where in the latter it generates a new `date/timestamp` version for `library root`:

[image]